# MongoDB: how to update only one element in the document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to updates only one element in the document to use put request

I tried

> PUT localhost:3000/api/memo/5b8e382d61984255d879f872

```
{
    text: "updated!"
{
```

but, it updated like this

```
{
    text: "updated!",
    imgUrl: null,
    tag: null,
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to updates one element in document?

```
await Memo.where('_id')
      .equals(req.params.id)
      .updateOne({
        imgUrl: req.body.imgUrl,
        text: req.body.text,
        tag: req.body.tag,
        user: req.body.user,
        loc: req.body.loc
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution to update only one element:

```
Memo.updateOne(
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e83957d56e802274d6") },
  { $set: { "text" : "updated" } });
```

UpdateOne() updates the first matching document in the collection that matches the filter.The above query operation updates a single document where text: "updated".

The operation can either replace an existing document or update specific fields in an existing document.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: UpdateOne() updates the first matching document in the collection that matches the filter.The above query operation updates a single document where text: "updated"

Comment: The operation can either replace an existing document or update specific fields in an existing document.

Comment: I put your comments in the answer, you can always edit your posts.